# C++0x TMP compilation speed

Tags: compiler-construction, c++11, template-meta-programming

This question focuses on template metaprogramming constructs. I have found two articles ([one](http://cpptruths.blogspot.com/2010/03/faster-meta-programs-using-gcc-45-and.html) and [two](http://boost-spirit.com/home/articles/qi-example/zero-to-60-mph-in-2-seconds/), two however doesn't show hard evidence, but I trust the claims) that provide a evidence showing that c++0x prototype compilers turn exponential compilation times to linear compilation times.

I have a vague inkling that auto, decltype and variadic templates will have something are enablers of this. What I would like to see is ground up explanation of the changes to the languages and the compiler technologies that enable this, especially explaining the how and why.

In terms of my skill level, I have used the boost TMP library spirit in anger, and some toy MPL programs.

Comment: Interesting, could you provide links to the two mentioned articles?

Comment: I've noticed that using `std::tuple` along with variadic templates has been much faster (and generated much cleaner errors) than using equivalent boost classes. I've even written a small subset of boost.mpl to use tuples. The compile times are down and the complexity is down.

Answer (score 3):

It's clear that the first is slower to process for the compiler than the second and there is, like you say, [evidence for that](http://www.generic-programming.org/~dgregor/cpp/variadic-templates.html).

```
/* first */
template<typename A>
void f(A const&);
template<typename A>
void f(A&);

template<typename A1, typename A2>
void f(A1 const&, A2&);
template<typename A1, typename A2>
void f(A1&, A2 const&);
template<typename A1, typename A2>
void f(A1 const&, A2 const&);
template<typename A1, typename A2>
void f(A1&, A2&);

// ...

/* second */
template<typename ...T>
void f(T &&...);
```

I know of no workaround for a completely generic `auto` in C++. Simulating `auto` requires hundreds if not thousands of lines of codes (see boost.typeof) and then it's still not generic. Same for `decltype`.

Comment: The problem compounds exponentially for libraries like spirit that use the template mechanism like prolog or haskell =D. variadic templates are one dimension of the  answer I'm looking for :D It's something to do with how the collection of new features interact to prevent the compiler taking 2 minutes to compile a spirit parser.